# citation of the same work by the same author and different years

Tags: citing, abnt, abntex2

I recently started using LaTeX to write my works. I would like to know how I can quote the same work by the same author in different years, writing something like:

> Nameauthor (2009; 2017)

I'm using `abntex2cite` and running something like:

```
\citeonline {nameauthor2009, nameauthor2017}
```

however this works no for me:

> Nameauthor (2009), Nameauthor (2017).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example!

Comment: Use biblatex with the biblatex-abnt style if you need to follow those rules.